# Using Angular service to provide data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I am building a SPA where one can open a dialog-window that contains a list of options. The user can pick an option, then said option should be attached to the main-view of the application (As in: pick *A* from a dialog, then attach *A* to an `<ul>` on the frontpage).

The dialog is independet and has its own module and controller:

```
var AdviceList = angular.module('adviceList', []);

AdviceList.controller('AdviceListCtrl',function($scope,$http){
   //...
});

AdviceList.provider('$adviceList',function(){
  this.$get = function ($rootScope,$document,$compile,$http){

    function AdviceList(){
      // ...
    }

    AdviceList.prototype.open = function(){
        // ...
    }
})
```

I do not understand how to share the list of chosen options with the rest of my application.

My approach was to create an array `activeOptions` and attach it to the controller's scope, but in that case, it will be out of reach for the provider:

```
AdviceList.controller('AdviceListCtrl',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.activeOptions = [];

    $scope.addAdvice = function(){

        $scope.activeOptions.push(); // push the chosen option

    }
 });


AdviceList.provider('$adviceList',function(){

this.$get = function ($rootScope,$document,$compile,$http){

    return{

        AdviceList: function(){
            return new AdviceList();
        },

        getActive: function(){
           // no access to the controllers scope here
        }

    }

  }
})
```

What is the recommended, best practice way of sharing data application wide and implement such functionality as i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the chosen options in the service/provider.  Provide an API on your service to store the  chosen options.  Have your AdviceListCtrl call that API/function to store the options.

Other entities that need to know what the chose options are can inject the service and call APIs on the service to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you, but i have to admit that i am not sure how to do that. How do i access the clicked element inside of the provider? ng-model won't point to the correct scope

Comment: @user2422960, ng-model is still used in the view associated with controller AdviceListController.  When an item is selected, a controller method can pass the value of the selected item to the service, using a method/API defined on the service.  The service can than store the value, and make it available to others via another method/API.

Comment: I did it. Finally. Thank you very much for your efforts and patience!